# sas proc export errors

Tags: sas, export, proc

I am trying to to use the proc export in SAS, and keep getting the same error:

```
ERROR: Export unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
Error creating XLSX file -> It is either not an Excel spreadsheet or it is damaged. Error code=8000101D Requested Output File is Invalid
```

sadly, I can't understand the meaning of the error

```
PROC EXPORT DATA=work.PANEL_SOFI 
            OUTFILE= "c:\\user\eyal\work.new_panel.xlsx" 
            DBMS=xlsx REPLACE ;
            SHEET="detailed" ;
RUN;
```

Comment: There should be more ERROR messages except the one NOTE

Comment: Error creating XLSX file -> It is either 
not an Excel spreadsheet or it is damaged.   Error code=8000101D
Requested Output File is Invalid

Comment: Google for 8000101D and you find the solution here:
https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/PROC-Export-to-Excel-is-giving-an-error/td-p/428289

Comment: thanks, but I already did that.

Comment: @EyalMarom i think you have no permisson to write in this folder.

Comment: It looks like your outfile `c:\\user\eyal\work.new_panel.xlsx` already existed and is corrupt. What happens if you rename the existing file?

Comment: @EyalMarom what have you tried from the proposed solutions in the linked article?

Comment: @Lee about your first comment, you are wrong. i've just tried to set "Deny" permission and execute this proc. As result there was same one error and same one note like in question.

Comment: @Alexey-sidiga But that was mentioned they said it is an problem with user rights and that is what you checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no permission to write in this folder. I've just tried to set "Deny" permission and execute this proc. As result there was same one error and same one note like in question.

Or excel file was [opened](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/09/24/proc-import-xlsx-error/) when you try to execute `proc export`.