# SAS PROC EXPORT and DBMS=CSV. ERROR: Export unsuccessful. See SAS Log for details

Tags: sas, export, export-to-csv, proc

I want to export multiple SAS datasets as CSV files (not as xlsx files) using SAS 9.4. When using the code for any of the datasets:

```
proc export data = dataset
    outfile = "C:\MBorg\dataset.csv"
    dbms = csv replace;
run;
```

I receive this error message:

```
ERROR: Export unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE EXPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.06 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Contrary to what the error message suggests, the SAS log provides no extra details.

Folder permissions or having Excel closed or open when running the code as per [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909548/sas-proc-export-errors), or using an empty dataset, makes no difference. The [SAS website](https://support.sas.com/kb/62/386.html) mentions that this error can occur when using PROC EXPORT with DBMS=CSV, and it can be avoided by using name-literal syntax. However, using it as per below makes no difference.

```
proc export data = work.'dataset'n
    outfile = "C:\MBorg\dataset.csv"
    dbms = csv replace;
run;
```

Strangely the only way I can find to circumvent the problem is resetting SAS. `options obs=max` makes no difference. Not sure what causes this message. This occurred with SAS 9.4 M0 and M7.

Any help with exporting CSV files without resetting SAS would be helpful.

Comment: You might have gotten an earlier error that changed something. For example it might have set the option OBS=0 which would prevent the data step that PROC EXPORT generates from reading/writing any data.

Comment: Do you know what errors could set that option?

Comment: @Tom tried options obs=max and it did not remove the code. This error seems to occur after prolonged use of SAS, and closing/reopening SAS is the only way I've found to circumvent it for the last few years.

Comment: Since you are writing text files you don't need to use PROC EXPORT.  Just write your own data step(s) to write the CSV files.  That might let you get a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your own step(s) to write the text file instead of asking PROC EXPORT to generate one for you.  That should at least make the error message clearer.

```
* Get list of variables names ;
proc transpose data=DATASET(obs=0) out=_names_; var _all_; run;
* Write header row ;
data _null_;
  file "C:\MBorg\dataset.csv" dsd lrecl=2000000 ;
  set _names_;
  put _name_ @ ;
run;
* Write data rows ;
data _null_;
  file "C:\MBorg\dataset.csv" dsd lrecl=2000000 mod;
  set DATASET;
  put (_all_) (+0) ;
run;
```

Comment: This didn't make the error message any clearer. But it did successfully output the CSV file without errors, even when the previous code was generating the error message.